# Flutter FireStore Apply Filter with onTap

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

String _currentlySelectedlanguage = "india";

class _SplitPageState extends State {
final List _dropdownValueslanguage = ["india", "usa"];

Widget dropdownWidgetlanguage() {
return DropdownButton(
isExpanded: false,
value: _currentlySelectedlanguage,
onChanged: (String newvalue) {
setState(() {
_currentlySelectedlanguage = newvalue;
print(_currentlySelectedlanguage);
});
},
items: _dropdownValueslanguage
.map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
child: Text(value),
value: value,
))
.toList(),
);
}

Comment: can you please share some code so we can help you.

Comment: Future getData() async {
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
        .collection('slideshow')
        .where("lang", isEqualTo: currentlySelectedlanguage)
        .get();
    return snapshot.docs;
  }

Comment: currentlySelectedlanguage is From My DropDown

Comment: Thank you for your reply , if thier is no solution can you tell me how to pass data ? i did all the ways not working:(

Comment: can you edit your questing with dropdown code?

Comment: edited , please check :)

Comment: all this code is in one file -.- i tried a lot to put the dropdown button to another page and pass the data , nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
class Code extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CodeState createState() => _CodeState();
}

String currentLanguage; //updated

class _CodeState extends State<Code> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        dropdownWidgetlanguage(),
        FutureBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
            future: getData(_currentlySelectedlanguage),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData){
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => snapshot.data[index].data()['name'],);
              }else{
                return Container();
              }
            },)
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget dropdownWidgetlanguage() {
    return DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: false,
      value: _currentlySelectedlanguage,
      onChanged: (String newvalue) {
        setState(() {
          _currentlySelectedlanguage = newvalue;
          currentLanguage = newvalue; //updated
        });
      },
      items: _dropdownValueslanguage
          .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(value),
                value: value,
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
  String _currentlySelectedlanguage;

  final List<String> _dropdownValueslanguage = ["USA", "India"];

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getData(String filter) async {
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
        .collection('slideshow')
        .where("lang", isEqualTo: filter)
        .get();
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
}
```

---

```
class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Class2State createState() => _Class2State();
}

class _Class2State extends State<SecondClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(currentLanguage),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir but i have no problem in the project , i want to get out the dropdown and put it in another page just use it for other pages for selecting language , i mean i will be able to change the language from one place , and every pages will change , do you think  there's a way to pass data ?! thanks

Comment: Make one **global variable**, Once you change language then update that variable and **use that global variable in all screens**.

Comment: i don't understand could u please write a example for me thanks

Comment: check updated code